# How to load arguments from a xml in oozie workflow

Tags: workflow, oozie

I want to load properties from a xml properties file for a oozie job. The file can be specified by -conf argument. Where should the file be placed so that oozie can pick up the properties file when the job starts.

```
<action name="start">
  <java>
     <main-class>com.oozieexample.Main</main-class>
     <arg>-conf</arg>
     <arg>run_configs.xml</arg>
     .....
     ....
```

In this example http://www.infoq.com/articles/oozieexample, action.xml file specified as argument file but location is not specified. What is the default location oozie looks for properties and how to give custom location. The workflow will be running from HDFS location.

Comment: in the same path as that of the workflow.xml

Answer (score 1):

1. upload your props file to an HDFS directory somewhere
2. tell Oozie to download the file into the YARN container used for execution with `<file>/some/hdfs/dir/run_configs.xml<file>`
3. your Java Action will find `run_configs.xml` in its current working directory

And now, pleeeeeeease, spend some time reading a **tutorial** about Oozie such as [this one](http://hadooped.blogspot.fr/2013/09/apache-oozie-part-12-passing-output.html) (a bit old but covers a lot of ground).